# Using TLS 1.2 with AWS Simple Email Service and PHPMailer

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, smtp, tls1.2, amazon-ses

I am currently running PHP 7 on Apache. I was using AWS SES with no problems untill they have now stopped supporting TLS 1.0 and 1.1 and now require 1.2. I have checked my phpinfo() and TLS 1.2 is supported.

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once("PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer;
try {
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Host = "email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = //username
    $mail->Password = //password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPOptions = [
        'ssl' => ['crypto_method' => STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_TLSv1_2_CLIENT]
    ];
    $mail->addReplyTo("test@example.com");
    $mail->addAddress("test@example.com");
    $mail->Subject = "test";
    $mail->Body = "test";
    $mail->send();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

The error that comes back with the Exception directly related to TLS version 1.0 and 1.1 no longer being supported despite me enabling it in my code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Just went though the same thing, and setting:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tlsv1.2";
```

solved it for us.